# Cordova app zooms on input after iOS 9 upgrade

Tags: cordova, zooming, ios9

I have a Cordova app which worked great on iOS 8. Now that my clients have upgraded to iOS 9 they started reporting that the application automatically zooms in on the input field when they try to log in.

I have reproduced the error on my end but am so far unable to find a solution. Any ideas how to prevent the zooming in on an input field?

Edit:
I use this viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

Comment: do you have a viewport meta tag in your app?

Comment: Yes. Just updated the questoin

Answer (score -1):

This is rather late, but here is a potential jumping off point:

https://github.com/rtoselli/ZoomReset/

I wasn't able to get it working, but you might have more luck than me.

Edit: Essentially, what the link is outlining is creating a custom Cordova plugin to reset the zoom in the uiwebview.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it's always better to include important parts of answer here and then add a link of reference. Link-only answers become invalid when the linked-pages change over time.